# Detect version of Chrome without using window.navigator.appVersion

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, version

---

EDIT: The question has become irrelevant as I discovered the setRequestHeader technique works on both v18 and v19. The poster on http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123150#c39 appears to be incorrect saying this method does not work on v18 - it does. I will update with this answer in 8 hrs when I am allowed!

---

I am using a Chrome extension which is an automatic testing tool. It has overridden user agent (by command line when starting chrome) so I can no longer see the version of chrome by using appVersion.

Is there some other way to detect the chrome version in Javascript?

Background: I am using xmlhttp to request a page protected by Basic Auth.

I must now take different action depending on v18 or v19+ as Google removed embedded basic auth in a URL at v19 (see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123150#c39).

This is an automatic script so I will not be there to enter username or password, but they are both known to the script.

```
if (v18_or_earlier)
{
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true, http_basic_username, http_basic_password) ;
}
else //v19+
{
    xmlhttp.open("POST", get_upload_url(), true);
    var auth_header = "Basic " + Base64.encode(http_basic_username + ":" + http_basic_password) ;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth_header) ;
}
xmlhttp.send(post_body) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
<script>  
function chrome_version( version ) {  
  if ( version < 18) {  
    xmlhttp.open("POST", get_upload_url(), true);  
    var auth_header = "Basic " + Base64.encode(http_basic_username + ":" +   http_basic_password) ;  
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth_header) ;  
  } else {  
  # Maybe do framebusting or...  
  xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true, http_basic_username, http_basic_password) ;  
  }     
}  
</script>  
<iframe src="http://user:pass@example.org"  
        onload="chrome_version(18)"  
        onerror="chrome_version(19)">  
</iframe>
```